# Suggestions for deciding on a WCMS for a hockey website?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, silverstripe

I need to make a website for my hockey club. My main purpose for this site is allowing people to sign in and post articles and training schedules in their section. Eg Mens, Womens, Juniors and Masters. I want to have some kind of upload manager that will allow them to choose where they post the info too (eg, Mens, Masters and Homepage).

This is the main functionality I'm looking for at the moment.

The clubs previous website used Joombla which I have hated. I found it to be way to restrictive. Its on a old version of it so there are probably many improvements in the new version but from what I've read it seems like it still has a lot of restrictions in how content is managed. I am open to trying it again tho.

I've used Wordpress before and liked it but that was on a small scale projects and I'm not sure it really fits what I'll be trying to do here, since it mostly deals with blog posts and I'll need to have functionality to upload and display files.

I've had a look around at some other ones like Squarespace and Silverstripe. I'm really liking the simplicity of silverstrip(one thing I hate about Joombla is the clutter on the opening page) and am leaning towards it right now if I can find a nice way to have people post news to multiple pages at once.

If anyone has any suggestions they'd be very welcome. I know html, css, javascript and a bit of php. I'm learning Ruby atm so wouldn't be against using it so I could learn more but it might be a bit much for a sports website.

Comment: I would say Silverstripe is a good CMS for this. I would recommend you  reading up on OOPHP and the MVC pattern, before going into writing a member system.

Answer (score 0):

First off, its nice to see someone that likes hockey too :) You can't use Squarespace, you'll need an Apache server for what you want. You will need some way to store information, so you'll need a MySQL database, probably some advanced knowledge of PHP (I'm assuming you don't know how to connect to databases and do some other functions). Wordpress is too limited, so you can't use that. I have never used Silverstripe personally, but it seems like the best of your options here. You'll probably need some more knowledge of PHP before you attempt to make a members system.

Comment: Yay for us hockey people! Learning more php would be useful so I'm not against this. I'll have to looking into it more